# What are parameters in php?

Tags: php, parameters

What are parameters in php?

I have looked online, and there are many different definitions, which is confusing for a newbie like myself.

The reason i ask is because i have the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpProject2/Area_Rest_page.php on line 22

Based on this code:

```
$sql=mysqli_query("SELECT Rest_Details.Resturant_ID,    
Rest_Details.Resturant_name, Rest_Details.Res_Address_Line_1, Rest_Details.City_name, 
 Rest_Details.Avg_Del,Delivery_Pcode.Pcode 
 FROM Rest_Details
 INNER JOIN Delivery_Pcode
 ON Delivery_Pcode.Restaurant_ID=Rest_Details.Restaurant_ID
 WHERE Delivery_Pcode.Pcode LIKE '%$searchq'") or die ("could not search!");
```

Line 22 is:

```
WHERE Delivery_Pcode.Pcode LIKE '%$searchq'") or die ("could not search!");
```

Comment: Parameters are the arguments that you pass to a function.... in the case of your code (see the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for details `mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`), the first mandatory parameter should be a database connection, and the second mandatory parameter should be the query string, with an optional third parameter for the result mode.... you are only passing the query string

Comment: In this case, the parameters are the items inside `mysqli_query()`. Your `SELECT` is the first parameter. The problem is, it needs to be the second parameter. The first parameter should be a database connection. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `mysqli_query` needs 2 variables passed to it. The one is the sql query, which you have provided, but it also needs to know to which mysql connection to query against.

Have a read on the official docs for [**mysqli_query**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), as well as [**function arguments**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

> Information may be passed to functions via the argument list, which is a comma-delimited list of expressions. The arguments are evaluated from left to right.

Here's an example using the function you're trying to use:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Create table doesn't return a resultset */
if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {
    printf("Table myCity successfully created.\n");
}
```

In the code above, we're first connecting to the database with `mysqli_connect`, and we save the return value of that function to the `$link` variable.

Then, to run our query with `mysqli_query` we pass in the  connection variable (`$link`) as well as the query.

Comment: oh thank you, that makes so much sense now, i will try that now